# Is there a JavaScript method for this logical problem?

Tags: javascript, methods, logic

I'm trying to solve a practice problem in JS and the idea of it is to use some methods and to make it the most efficient way as possible.

**The problem:**

I have to find how many times I can form the word *DOGGY* inside a given string of uppercase letters.

For examples:

- Inside the string 'DHTHTOMMGGSDY' I can form the word *DOGGY* only 1 time.
- Inside the string 'DXOXGGYDXOXGGY' I can form the word *DOGGY* 2
  times.
- Inside the string 'DXOXGXY' I can form the word *DOGGY* 0
  times.

Is there a method I can use to solve it?

I was trying to parse the string to an array with spread operator `[...string]` and then using the method `filter()` to return a variable with the filtered words but had problems with the 'G's becouse they have to repeat.

**This is where I've got so far:**

```
let result = [...string].filter((char) => {
        let word = char !== 'D' && char !== 'O' && char !== 'G' && char !== 'G' && char !== 'Y';
        console.log(word);
    });

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: nope, got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

Comment: almost there.. now it always returns `0`

Comment: It just works weird for me.. now it is returning only `2` even with this string: 'DXOXGGY'

Comment: Yep, in that case it returns `2` but with this string:  `DXOXGGY` it also returns `2` and it shouled be `1`

Comment: oops, yeah, I did it wrong - forgot the `g` flag :p

Comment: I'm still stucked with this exercise. Tried with the g flag but it always returns `0`. This is what I'm doing: `let result = S.match(/(D.?O.?G.?G.?Y)/g)?.length ?? 0;`

Comment: which isn't what I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a day or two and hundreds of cups of coffee late. If you find a bug break it to me gently please...

```js
      const searchString = "DOGGY";
      const targetStrings = [
        "DHTHTOMMGGSDY",
        "DXOXGGYDXOXGGY",
        "DXOXGXY"
      ];
      const searchArray = searchString.split("");

      console.log("searchString", searchString);
      console.log("****************************");

      targetStrings.forEach(function (targetString) {
        const targetArray = targetString.split("");
        console.log("targetString", targetString);
        let occurrences = 0;
        while (true) {
          let allCharsFound = searchArray.every(function (char) {
            const index = targetArray.indexOf(char);
            if (index === -1) {
              return false;
            }
            targetArray.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
          });
          if (allCharsFound) {
            occurrences++;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        
        console.log("occurrences", occurrences);
        console.log("----------------------------");

      });
```

Comment: Thanks @user3425506, It works great! I'm sorry I saw your response just now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this simple way

```js
let dog = "DXOXGGYDXOXGGY";
dog = dog.split("X").join('');
const dogs = dog.match(/DOGGY/g).length;

console.log(dogs)
```

Comment: I didn't put this example at the original question but there are strings like this too: `DHTHTOMMGGSDY`, and in this cases it won't work. I'm gonna add it now, thanks for your answer tho

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and includes

```js
    function findPhrase(input, searchedPhrase) {
        const inputWithSearchedPhraseLettersOnly = [...input].filter(letter => searchedPhrase.includes(letter)).join('');
    
        return inputWithSearchedPhraseLettersOnly;
    }
    (() => {
        const input = 'DXOXGGYDXOXGGYXXXDOXXGXXXGYX';
        const searchedPhrase = 'DOGGY';
        const result = findPhrase(input, searchedPhrase).split(searchedPhrase).length - 1;
        console.log(result);
    })();
```

Comment: Hi, it always returns 0 for me.